# Find recursive/xargs/cp/awk/sed/single quote in single quote together in a one-liner

Tags: shell, awk, sed, xargs, cp

I am trying to create a shell one liner to find all jpegs in a directory recursively. Then I want to copy them all out to an external directory, while renaming them according to their date and time and then append a random integer in order to avoid overwrites with images that have the same timestamp.

First Attempt:

`find  /storage/sdcard0/tencent/MicroMsg/ -type f  -iname '*.jpg' -print0 | xargs -0 sh -c 'for filename; do echo "$filename" && cp "$filename" $(echo /storage/primary/legacy/image3/$(stat $filename  |awk '/Mod/ {print $2"_"$3}'|sed s/:/-/g)_$RANDOM.jpg);done' fnord`

Among other things, the above doesn't work because there are the single quotes of the awk within the sh -c single quotes.

The second attempt should do the same thing without sh -c, but gives me this error on stat:

```
stat: can't stat '': No such file or directory
/system/bin/sh: file: not found
```

Second Attempt:

`find  /storage/sdcard0/tencent/MicroMsg/ -type f  -iname '*.jpg' -print0 | xargs -0 file cp "$file" $(echo /storage/primary/legacy/image3/$(stat "$file" | awk '/Mod/ {print $2"_"$3}'|sed s/:/-/g)_$RANDOM.jpg)`

I think the problem with the second attempt may be too many subshells?

Can anyone help me know where I'm going wrong here?

On another note: if anyone knows how to preserve the *actual* modified date/time stamps when copying a file, I would love the throw that in here.

Thank you Thank you

Comment: What's the fascination with a one-liner?  It just makes for unreadable code.  If you mean a single pipeline, that's rather different; it doesn't have to be on a single line.

Comment: You can choose to write a script rather than going for an "untidy" single liner to make it unreadable.

Comment: Does it have to use all these commands?  Could it just use Perl or Python?  Could you write a shell script that processes a list of files (`for file in "$@"; do …code here for one file…; done`) and then use `find … -exec script.sh {} +`.  That avoids needing `xargs`.  You can probably use `stat -c '%y'` (or `%Y`) to get the file modification time, saving the post-processing of the output of `stat`.

Comment: I agree, very messy. I would definitely be open to having this run in a script, but was also interested to see how all this could fit together.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use Perl or Python as I am trying to run this in the busybox shell of an android phone

Comment: Q: "I have written a complete mess and now it doesn't work - how can I fix it?" A: "Re-write it so it's not a complete mess, then ask for help if it still doesn't work". Simple...

Answer (score 0):

Were it my problem, I'd create a script — call it `filecopy.sh` — like this:

```
TARGET="/storage/primary/legacy/image3"
for file in "$@"
do
    basetime=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d.%H-%M-%S' -d @$(stat -c '%Y' "$file"))
    cp "$file" "$TARGET/$basetime.$RANDOM.jpg"
done
```

The `basetime` line runs `stat` to get the modification time of the file in seconds since The Epoch, then uses that with `date` to format the time as a modified ISO 8601 format (using `-` in place of `:`, and `.` in place of `T`).  This is then used to create the target file name, along with a semi-random number.

Then the `find` command becomes simply:

```
SOURCE="/storage/sdcard0/tencent/MicroMsg"
find "$SOURCE" -type f -iname '*.jpg' -exec /path/to/filecopy.sh {} +
```

Personally, I'd not bother to try making it work without a separate shell script.  It could be done, but it would not be trivial:

```
SOURCE="/storage/sdcard0/tencent/MicroMsg"
find "$SOURCE" -type f -iname '*.jpg' -exec bash -c \
    'TARGET="/storage/primary/legacy/image3"
     for file in "$@"
     do
         basetime=$(date +%Y-%m-%d.%H-%M-%S -d @$(stat -c %Y "$file"))
         cp "$file" "$TARGET/$basetime.$RANDOM.jpg"
     done' command {} +
```

I've taken some liberties in that by removing the single quotes that I used in the main shell script. They were optional, but I'd use them automatically under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Parallel > version 20140722 you can run:

```
find . | parallel 'cp {} ../destdir/{= $a = int(10000*rand); $_ = `date -r "$_" +%FT%T"$a"`; chomp; =}'
```

It will work on file names containing ' and space, but fail on file names containing ".

All new computers have multiple cores, but most programs are serial in nature and will therefore not use the multiple cores. However, many tasks are extremely parallelizeable:

- Run the same program on many files
- Run the same program for every line in a file
- Run the same program for every block in a file

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

A personal installation does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel